# How to use django-allauth app for github signup

Tags: python, django, github, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use **django-allauth** for signup/login with github in my web application; following http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ documentation I reached till Post Instillation and stuck from configuration heading. Have successfully modify settings.py, urls.py, run command for updating database "python manage.py syncdb" also when start admin page at local host added social account app for github, added client_id and secret_id provided after adding new application on github. But now what? What am I suppose to do next? Unable to understand next instructions written here http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration.

Please guide me what to do next. I want to let my user to signup using their github account, and want to read their basic information plus their repository informations, number of commits they made in any particular project/repository. I need to specify scope for the amount of information I want to access but where? Also is there any other better way to achieve it?

I am new to web-development and Django. Using django 1.6.2 and python 2.7 on Ubuntu in virtual environment(venv).

Comment: Any error? Just enter on the /accounts/login URL to login.

Comment: @jordiburgos: Sorry for replaying too late. Problem is that I have followed steps before configuration(given on webpage mentioned above), where to use those available settings and how.
Also as you mentioned to go on /accunts/login URL there I am getting 404, page not found error.